# "new" blog link in header pointed to a view without the new post

Tags: bug, blog

Clicking the blog link in the header on any meta currently takes you to

```
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blt=1
```

which didn't display the new blog post for a non-trivial amount of time. You had to remove the `blt` parameter to actually see [the new entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/highlights-from-stack-overflow-worldwide-meetups/). Assuming it was a caching issue, shouldn't the cache for both routes be refreshed when a new blog entry is posted?

Likewise, links to new posts in the Community Bulletin can have a similar problem, leading to erroneous 404s like the one shown below:

[image: unexpected 404 page on blog]

Comment: Oh, so *that's* what happened.

Comment: Nice. I just assumed it was a random glitch on my end and went back to work.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well, if it got you working...maybe it's `bydesign`

Comment: Seems to work okay with the parameter

Comment: @random Yes, seems fixed now. It makes sense that it was a caching issue, but seems like the cache for that view should be purged when new things are posted, since getting the notification and being shown an old blog entry is confusing.