# Blog showing up as mobile, won't exit

Tags: bug, blog

Stack Exchange blog is showing me the mobile site and won't let me exit on Chrome 21.

Could someone take a look? Thanks.

**Edit** I noticed it was with the special query string, that I can't exit it.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blb=1

Comment: Repro Chrome 20, Chrome 22.

Comment: Repro chrome 19. EEEEK

Comment: Not seeing this. Transient problem? cc @BenBrocka

Comment: Not seeing this either on Chrome 19. Tried while logged in to Wordpress and not logged in to Wordpress (sometimes does odd things), but didn't see. Tried with and without special query string, no mobile site trap.

Comment: Didn't even know the blog has mobile version... can't see it though getting only the ordinary blog. Did you find what happened by now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm pretty sure it's due to the blog's caching [being a bit haywire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131228/new-blog-link-in-header-pointed-to-a-view-without-the-new-post), but hard to say for certain. We can always just blame WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Reproduced in chrome 31.0.1650.63 on windows 8.1, but only in an incognito window. Nothing much I can do about it except blaming WordPress...

[image]

Comment: But why it happens only to some users? Same browser here, can't see that mobile version.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: My hypothesis: race condition bug in the Wordpress mobile device detector. Shared global state flips the state for multiple visitors when only one uses an actual mobile device to visit the site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I just saw the site flip to mobile, then on a later visit flip back to the desktop state. I had not changed a thing other than let a few minutes pass.

Comment: I can now trigger it at will. Steps to reproduce: Use a mobile device, click on the *blog* link in the footer. Then visit the same link from a desktop browser, you'll get the mobile version.

Comment: And I switched it back by using the *exit mobile version* link on my mobile device!

Comment: This may be tied to IP address; e.g. it may be limited to others behind a shared IP address using a mobile device.

Comment: @MartijnPieters We use some caching plugin (I forget which one). I wonder if that's the culprit here where it caches a certain view per IP/device/account?

Comment: @AnnaLear: sounds like a plausible culprit. It probably won't support 'Vary:' headers, will it? Otherwise you'd include User-Agent in that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the caching plugin we use, WP Super Cache, is to blame. (Many thanks to [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) for investigating and pointing me in the right direction.)

I'll see if we can tweak the settings to fix this up, but I'll be honest - fighting with Wordpress is fairly low priority at the moment.

Comment: Same issue as ["new" blog link in header pointed to a view without the new post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131228) then.