# Clicking a community bulletin blog link traps me in mobile view for some articles

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, blog

Similarly to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137360/blog-showing-up-as-mobile-wont-exit) (*now fixed*) where the slug `?blb=1` was forcing the blog to remain in mobile view in Chrome, I'm now experiencing the same issue with links form the community bulletin with the slug `?cb=1`.

For example, when I click a blog link to [The War of the Closes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1) *from the community bulletin* I am presented with the mobile view.  When I click the exit button in the footer the page reloads, still in the mobile view - I'm stuck.  Removing the `?cb=1` slug takes me back to a normal view.

I've just noticed that I can **only reproduce this on the War of the Closes Article**, though it persists after a cache clear and in incognito.

```
Chrome 27.0.14
Windows 7
```

Comment: Confirmed this just happened to myself, I came here to post this, but saw your question. I am using Windows XP (work choice, not mine) and Firefox 21.0

Comment: This is currently happening on the Stack Exchange for Android blog link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/?cb=1

Comment: ... and now it's not anymore.

Comment: can't repro this at all... ideas?

Comment: @Sklivvz: visit the same URL with a mobile device, *then* visit from the desktop again.

Comment: Erm, I *meant* to dupe this to [Blog showing up as mobile, won't exit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137360)