# Blog link in footer redirects to mobile version

Tags: bug, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blog showing up as mobile, won't exit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137360/blog-showing-up-as-mobile-wont-exit)

The link in the footer to the Stack Overflow blog leads to the mobile version of the blog, even if a non-mobile device is used.

After entering the mobile version of the blog, clicking on the "Exit the Mobile Edition" link does nothing. However, clicking on one of the blog posts in the list directs you to the standard browser view.

Typing the URL `http://blog.stackoverflow.com` directly into the address bar works fine.

Using IE8. Haven't tested in other browsers.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting the mobile version currently (although at the time the other question was posted, I did, and also couldn't "exit")

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely the same problem as the other question. I'm also getting http://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blb=1.

Comment: I have a feeling this all relates back to [a caching issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131228/new-blog-link-in-header-pointed-to-a-view-without-the-new-post) with the routes that have a query string, as well as the separate issue of the exit link not functioning correctly.